# Minimization of a fraction in 5 variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization

I need to minimize following fraction.
$$ a,b,c,d,e,f \in \mathbb{N}$$
$$ 1 \leq a,b,c,d,e,f \leq 7 $$
$$ \frac{a^2\cdot b^2 \cdot c \cdot d}{e \cdot f} $$

The quotient needs to be the smallest possible integer. All variables need to be different.

I thought to put for e and f, 6 and 2 because of prime factorization. Then the smallest numbers left 1 and 3 for a and b and at least 4 and 5 for c and d. This results in 15. I need to prove this now.
But I am not sure how to start.
I would appreciate any help and thank you for your time.

Comment: $e, f$ cannot be $5$ or $7$ because of prime factorization. Either $a$ or $b$ has to be $1$ so you can remove one variable. The remaining cases can be written by hand.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is so small, that a computer handles this in less than a second. To see this, the variable assignments correspond to the first 6 entries of a permutation of the vector $\{1,\ldots,7\}$. Thus, the number of variable assignments is at most $7! = 5040$, which is tiny for modern computers. Brute force gives
$$[a,b,c,d,e,f] =[2,1,6,5,4,3]$$
as the optimal solution, with objective value $10$.